# magento2 add where in _initSelect

Tags: magento2.3.5-p1

I have writed in Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection

I don't know if i write this way. It working

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();

    $tableDescription = $this->getConnection()->describeTable($this->getMainTable());
    foreach ($tableDescription as $columnInfo) {
        $this->addFilterToMap($columnInfo['COLUMN_NAME'], 'main_table.' . 
$columnInfo['COLUMN_NAME']);
    }
    
    $this->getSelect()->where("main_table.status='pending'");
    
    return $this;
}
```

But it not working with this way

```
<?php

namespace Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;


class Collection extends 
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult
{

public function __construct(
    EntityFactory $entityFactory,
    Logger $logger,
    FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
    EventManager $eventManager,
    $mainTable = 'sales_order_grid',
    $resourceModel = \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order::class
) {
    parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, 
$eventManager, $mainTable, $resourceModel);
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
protected function _initSelect()
{
    if($this->request->getParam('status')){
        $paramStatus = $this->request->getParam('status');
    }
    parent::_initSelect();

    $tableDescription = $this->getConnection()->describeTable($this->getMainTable());
    foreach ($tableDescription as $columnInfo) {
        $this->addFilterToMap($columnInfo['COLUMN_NAME'], 'main_table.' . 
$columnInfo['COLUMN_NAME']);
    }
    if(isset($paramStatus)){
        $this->getSelect()->where("main_table.status='$paramStatus'");
    }
    return $this;
}
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: Share  the full code of this the files

Comment: i have edit it!

Answer (score 0):

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();

    $tableDescription = $this->getConnection()->describeTable($this->getMainTable());
    foreach ($tableDescription as $columnInfo) {
        $this->addFilterToMap($columnInfo['COLUMN_NAME'], 'main_table.' . 
$columnInfo['COLUMN_NAME']);
    }
    if($this->request->getParam('status')){
        $this->getSelect()->where("main_table.status='.$this->request->getParam('status').'");
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: i don't know i echo exit the $this->getSelect() and run ib database it working but view in backend it show all and not working with where

Comment: i don't know if it's in if then it doesn't run